# lubuntu 14.10: Coniguration for anthy/Japanese input

Tags: lubuntu, 14.10, input-method, japanese

I have a fresh install of lubuntu 14.10. Unfortunately, I cannot find the configuration for enabling the hiragana-input (any longer).

Previously, I had no problems setting it up on lubuntu 13.10, and after upgrading to 14.nn it still worked flawlessly.

But now I am completely at a loss. Where did this go?

I can add a "Japanese input method". But the input is fixed on "romaji" (no hiragana).

- "Language Support Japanese" is installed.
- ibus is installed and set.
- anthy is installed (but not accessible?).

How can I enable the ibus-anthy? By GUI or text configs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enable it via *IBus Preferences*, which can be started from some menu item (I think) or via the command `ibus-setup` in a terminal window.

Comment: In the preferences, tab "General" contains "shortcuts", "fonts and style"; tab "Input Method" "add"/"remove" ("preferences" is greyed out); tab "Advanced" "Keyboard Layout (use system..)", "Global input method settings". I think I should be able to change to anthy in tab "Input Method", but there is no such thing.

Comment: @tokosh: Sorry, I don't know what the Lubuntu menu system looks like. Then open a terminal window and run the `ibus-setup` command.

Comment: The description above is from the "IBus Preferences". Sorry, I should have been more precise.

Comment: @tokosh: Aha, ok. In the "Input Method" tab you should click the "Add" button to add _Japanese - Anthy_.

Comment: Ah, I had tried this many times. But your comment made try another time: The Japanese-Anthy option is not visible as a proposed item. Only when I looked for it (the search box), it appeared. Once again I feel a bit stupid having asked this question (it's not the first that was in the end rather easy .. and spending so much time on it). Thanks, Gunnar.

Comment: `ibus-setup` was helpful (I used to access it via menus). And the particular dialog is afaik the same as in Ubuntu.

Comment: @tokosh: Great that you figured it out. Actually, the dialog isn't used in the latest Ubuntu versions, since ibus has been integrated with the System Settings menu.